# Is it legal to sell days of use for an android application on a web site?

Tags: android, google-play

I have to make an android application, distributed free on Google Play, but can not be used unless you buy days of use. So I thought to make a website where the user can log in and buy his days of use, because the client wants the user to buy these on a tablet or on a PC.

The big question I ask myself is : is that it is legal to have a free application on Google Play, then selling days of use out of the application on a web site?

Comment: Maybe a bit off topic but I would recommend to use the In-app-billing system offered by Google. Especially subscriptions: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html Also I would say it's legal to have some-kind of subscription system in your app because In-app-billing has the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use the in-app-billing because user must be able to buy the products on a computer. I wonder if it's legal to sell it on a website because in this case, unlike in-app purchases, Google will not have 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no official resources but I can't see why it would be illegal to sell goods for your app on your own website.

Although I would recommend to use the default In-app-billing system if possible.

Also the 30% (In-app-billing) that normally "goes to Google" are transaction costs so when you sell using your own transaction system there is no point in saying Google misses "income" because you don't use their service.

Their are many web-shop apps that sell goods on their own website without using any Google service, again I see no point why the same would be illegal for subscriptions.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/policies/index.html

Comment: Okay thanks, i didn't know that about the 30% :). I really can't use the in-app-billing because it requires that the user can make purchases on a computer.